# How to assign struct element pointer values to each other?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, structure, bubble-sort

I'm trying to implement a BubbleSort-Algorithm into my C-Program to sort elements of structures (for example by "name"-elements) inside of a doubly linked list, containing entries of games I like.
When I'm trying to assign an element to another of the same type, I get this error message:

> [Error] assignment to expression with array type

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
typedef struct game {
    char name[50];
    float price;
    int release;
    char genre[30];
    struct game *next; /*points to the next structure and to NULL if it's the last one*/
    struct game *prev; /*points to the previous structure and to NULL if it's the first one*/
}game;

typedef struct {
    struct game *first; /*points to the first element*/
    struct game *now; /*points to the element currently viewed*/
    struct game *last; /*points to the last element*/
}s_field;

void swap(s_field *lib) {
    char *tempName;
    tempName = lib->now->name;
    lib->now->name = lib->now->next->name; /*This is the line where I first get the error*/
    lib->now->next->name = tempName;
    /*There are assignments like those above for every other variable here*/
}
```

swap(s_field *lib) is being executed within the main-function.
Is there a way to circumvent this problem? For example by some sort of typecast?

Comment: The data member name is an array. Arrays do not have the assignment operator. Use the string function  strcpy or memcpy.

Comment: Thank you @VladfromMoscow, it worked!

Comment: Arrays do not have the assignment operator, but struct types do. One option would be to enclose the "payload" of the list element (everything but the link pointers) in a sub structure and use the assignment operator to copy the payload between the list elements and a temporary variable. However, underneath the covers, the compiled C code may be using an inline memcpy or an internal function call to copy the payload structure.

Comment: Another thing to consider is that since you have a doubly linked list, you could swap the order of the elements on the list by manipulating the list pointers rather than swapping the contents. That is the conventional way of swapping the order of items on a linked list.

Comment: tempName works because you are just getting a pointer to the array.  However, for the other statements you are trying to change the contents of that array.  You'll need to use strcpy() instead.